# .bat file giving false positives

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i am setting up a bat file to start up all of my game servers when i activate it. the bat file is intended to check if the file is active and if not it starts the file. i have 2 nested bats one activates all the bats so i can have a status monitor while the master starts the monitor bats. my master is giving false positives and i don't know why it is the same code from my server checking bat"monitor bats" and they work just fine. please help

EX: below

Master.bat

```
@echo off
Title Check for running process . . .
mode con cols=90 lines=3
set "MyProcess1=FactorioTestIfActive.bat"
set "MyProcess2=RustTestIfActive.bat"
set "MyProcess3=ArkTestIfActive.bat"
set delay=30
:Main
cls
:T1 Tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %MyProcess1%" | find /I "%MyProcess1%">nul && (
echo( & Color 9A
echo         PROCESS "%MyProcess1%" IS RUNNING !
)&&(
Timeout /T %delay% /nobreak>nul
Goto :T2
)||(
echo( & Color 4C
echo        PROCESS "%MyProcess1%" IS NOT RUNNING !
)&&(
GOTO :StartScripts1
)

:T2 Tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %MyProcess2%" | find /I "%MyProcess2%">nul && (
echo( & Color 9A
echo         PROCESS "%MyProcess2%" IS RUNNING !
)&&(
Timeout /T %delay% /nobreak>nul
Goto :T3
)||(
echo( & Color 4C
echo        PROCESS "%MyProcess2%" IS NOT RUNNING !
)&&(
GOTO :StartScripts2
)

:T3 Tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %MyProcess3%" | find /I "%MyProcess3%">nul && (
echo( & Color 9A
echo         PROCESS "%MyProcess3%" IS RUNNING !
)&&(
Timeout /T %delay% /nobreak>nul
Goto :ALL
)||(
echo( & Color 4C
echo        PROCESS "%MyProcess3%" IS NOT RUNNING !
)&&(
GOTO :StartScripts3
)

:StartScripts1 

cd /d "D:\ServerBAT\"
start cmd /k CALL FactorioTestIfActive.bat

Timeout /T %delay% /nobreak>nul

Goto Main

:StartScripts2 

cd /d "D:\ServerBAT\"
start cmd /k CALL RustTestIfActive.bat

Timeout /T %delay% /nobreak>nul

Goto Main

:StartScripts3 

cd /d "D:\ServerBAT\"
start cmd /k CALL ArkTestIfActive.bat

Timeout /T %delay% /nobreak>nul

Goto Main

:ALL

echo( & Color 9A
echo         ALL PROCESS ARE RUNNING !
    )

Timeout /T %delay% /nobreak>nul

Goto Main


pause
```

EX: below

monitor.bats

```
@echo off
Title Check for running process . . .
mode con cols=50 lines=3
set "MyProcess1=factorio.exe"

set delay=10
:Main
cls
Tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %MyProcess1%" | find /I "%MyProcess1%">nul && (
echo( & Color 9A
echo         PROCESS "%MyProcess1%" IS RUNNING !
)&&(
Timeout /T %delay% /nobreak>nul
Goto Main
)||(
echo( & Color 4C
echo        PROCESS "%MyProcess1%" IS NOT RUNNING !
)&&(
GOTO :StartScripts
)

:StartScripts 

cd /d "D:\FactorioServer\"
start cmd /k CALL FactorioServer.bat

Timeout /T %delay% /nobreak>nul


Goto Main
```

i learn from taking something that already exists and making something from it and merging others together i learn from troubleshooting work from others molded to what i am trying to use it for. so if you see you code in this i am sorry but i am trying to learn how bat files are written and the structure of the code.

Comment: i think i have the bat file detection correct but my if statement is wrong i do not understand what the error level means i am familiar with java && = and as well as || = or and so i am very confused on if statements in a bat file

Comment: :T1
     Tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq  cmd.exe" | find /I "WINDOWTITLE eq 
     %MyProcess1%"  && (
     echo( & Color 9A
     echo         PROCESS "%MyProcess1%" IS RUNNING ! 
     Goto :T2
     )>nul ||(
     echo( & Color 4C
     echo        PROCESS "%MyProcess1%" IS NOT RUNNING !
     GOTO :StartScripts1
     )